# Ubuntu does not start anymore

Tags: 16.04, fsck, busybox

after my laptop was frozen, I shut down my laptop with the Power Button (long press). After Restart it shows:

[image]

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your volume requires a file system check (`fsck`) to repair any bad sectors/blocks - you can initiate this using the following command in the prompt you're seeing:

`fsck -y /dev/sda1`

It's likely that your machine crashed, and the force shutdown caused this.